# GnuTLS: Failed to acquire random data with GIT_SSH_COMMAND

Tags: windows, git, gnutls

I have a script that tries to clone Git repositories in the background, without the user being able to provide credentials. Thus, it sets `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` to enable OpenSSH batch mode. Example script that reproduces the problem:

```
import subprocess, sys
popen = subprocess.Popen(
  ['git', 'clone', 'https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/flux.git'],
  env={'GIT_SSH_COMMAND': 'ssh -oBatchMode=yes'},
)
popen.wait()
sys.exit(popen.returncode)
```

Without setting `GIT_SSH_COMMAND`, the command runs fine. But with it, I get

```
C:\Users\niklas\Desktop
λ test
Cloning into 'flux'...
Error in GnuTLS initialization: Failed to acquire random data.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/NiklasRosenstein/flux.git/': Couldn't resolve host 'github.com'
```

What's going wrong here? Using Git-for-Windows 2.6.1.windows.1

Comment: Did you find any solution? We are facing a similar Problem.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your repository URL.  You want to be using the ssh or git protocol, not http/https.